# Can I pay visa fees directly

Tags: uk-visa, payment

I am intending to apply for a UK spouse visa on the 1st of November but my wife cannot pay the fee with her card. In Tunisia, my country, it has a closed economy; we can't pay online for anything. I was told to pay in cash at TLScontact Tunisia, but I don't know if I can do that and, if so, what to do on the application form. Is there any option to skip paying online and pay just the immigration health surcharge directly to the National Health Service?

Comment: For the sake of clarification, the immigration health surcharge is not paid directly to NHS even when you pay online. UKVI collects the surcharge and the Government allocates that to the NHS. Unfortunately I don't know the answer to the payment method part, sorry.

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, you will have to pay any visa application fee after paying for the IHS. Does your question intend to cover both, or do they subject to different treatment with regard to payment method?

Comment: No I will pay the NHS online but I want to know if I can pay the visa fee in cash at the VAC

Comment: Who told you that you can pay in cash?

Comment: In tunisia and morroco they can pay in cash as I was told in a Facebook group for ppl paid recently

Comment: One reason that fees must be paid only through specific, authorised channels is to avoid fraud, misuse, abuse. A Facebook group is not a reliable source.

Comment: @Giorgio Paying fees in cash is acceptable in some countries. The TLS website for Tunisia suggests not, but it’s quite possible that it’s wrong.

Comment: @MJeffryes understood, but it has to be done at an official visa centre (not a visa agent). It's unclear why OP is asking, after being told that cash would be accepted at TSLContact centre Tunis, which is the company authorised by UKVI.

Comment: Thank you I asked and they confirmed that I can pay in cash

Comment: Can you put your latest comment as an answer, so that people who come after you can benefit?

Answer (score 4):

Yes I called tlscontact Tunisia they confirmed that I can pay just the visa fee in cash but IHS should be paid online